# Error! Some required system tools for security patches magento

Tags: security, magento, patch

Error! Some required system tools, that are utilized in this sh script, are not installed:
Tool(s) "patch" is(are) missed, please install it(them).

is there any thing I am missing?

**EDIT:**

I am running patch for magento version 1.7.0.2

PATCH_SUPEE-2677_EE_1.13.0.2_v2.sh file is showing this error.

Comment: Server issue - it's missing stuff.

Comment: `sudo yum install patch`

Answer (score 7):

I got the solutions. Here is my method. I hope it will help the others too

1. Use the attached patch file and upload the same in root folder of magento
   The file is having extension .sh
2. use putty or any other command line tool to access the shell commands.
3. Go the path where the file is available. i.e.

   cd /var/www/html/magento
4. then run the command

sh PATCH_SUPEE-2677_EE_1.13.0.2_v2.sh

1. If error comes then try to use the command
   yum install patch
2. again run the sh command

Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.

1. The process is complete. to make the impact

Once that is done, refresh the cache in the Admin under "System > Cache Management" so that the changes will be reflected. We highly recommend you test all patches in a test environment before taking them live.